# Which push notification method to use for both iOS and android

Tags: push-notification

i need to add push notifications to the "App" the "App" is cross platform that is Android and iOS , im doing to server side its not a problem , but   what is my   problem is i don't know which services to use .
do i use the native Apple Push Notification Service and in Android i use the Cloud Messaging ( or other native Android push service )
or i use the google : Cloud Messaging for both iOS and android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my opinion you should use Apple Push service for iOS and GCM for android.

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 choices:

1. Use APNS for iOS,  and GCM for Android.
2. Use GCM for both Android and iOS.
3. Use 3rd party sevices like parse.com, urbanairship, ...  for all platforms (iOS, Android, windows, Unity,...)
4. Write the server-side yourself to support all platforms.

**Reviews**

- Using APNS and GCM may be best by performance,  as there is no other 3rd party there,  but you have to build a server which can support both services. You wouldn't be paid in this choice.
- Using GCM for both sides is another free choice choice in which you have to do implement only connection with GCM.
- Using other 3rd party services like parse.com is very easy and can done within minutes, but you may be charged if you have a lot of transactions. Although by using parse.com you have more coverage on android devices. (e.g. GCM doesn't support android devices with no google play sevices APK installed)
- Writing a server-side is very hard and time consuming, so do that if you really have no other choices. (like you want to run something like Whatsapp or Viber)

Now you should choose.